# CSS media query not being applied

Tags: css

[This site](http://staging.taxrusaccounting.com.au/) uses the style sheet [`http://staging.taxrusaccounting.com.au/wp-content/themes/bones-new/library/css/style.css`](http://staging.taxrusaccounting.com.au/wp-content/themes/bones-new/library/css/style.css) which contains the media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav li {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
}
```

However, the `.nav li` rule is not present in Chrome Inspector when the viewport is wider than 768px.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Try css with "!important", if needs to override forcefully

Comment: @NitinDhomse. If the rule were loading but not being applied, adding `!important` may resolve the issue, but the rule is not loading - it isn't present in Chrome Inspector.

Comment: Now check  "style.css"  file is  present or not in Chrome's source tab (F12)

Comment: Yes @NitinDhomse it is: `http://staging.taxrusaccounting.com.au/wp-content/themes/bones-new/library/css/style.css`

Comment: Thanks @NitinDhomse you're right. Weird. I can see the file exists in FileZilla @ `/staging/wp-content/themes/bones-new/library/css/style.css`

Answer (score 1):

Found a typo

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px} {
```

should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
```